# Run Azure Function every 3 days

Tags: azure, cron, azure-functions

I want to create a cron expression to run Azure Function every 3 days at 12:00 PM

I created this: 0 0 */72 * * *
From my understanding, it should make the function run every 72 hours. When I run my function locally I see:
[image]

Looks like function will be run everyday. What's wrong? How to specify also the time at which function will start (12:00 PM)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: as per @markxa mentioned, it will run at 12:00pm every 3rd day of the month.
Please use this: `0 0 12 1/3 * *`.

Test result as below:
[image]

Comment: What's the diffence between */3 ad 1/3? They seem to give same result

Comment: No more difference, some tools like [CronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/) will generate some little difference, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the */72 doesn't mean "every 72 hours", it essentially means "when the hour modulo 72 is zero" which is only true when the hour itself is zero. The nearest you can get with a standard expression is `0 0 12 */3 * *` which will run at 12:00pm every 3rd day of the month. Unfortunately this will give you a gap that's not 3 days at the end of any month that doesn't have 30 days; if that's not acceptable then you'll have to run it every day with `0 0 12 * * *` and keep the last run time in persistent storage somewhere in your function code so you can only actually do the processing every 3 days.

Comment: Interesting. In such case probbaly it'll b better to provide interval using Timespan. That requires switching to AppServicePlan however.